# why run fp.tell inside of for line in open() not correctly in python2.7.13?

Tags: python-2.7

see the example in `python2`:

```
In [25]: fp = open('a','rb',0)

In [26]: for i in fp:
    ...:     print(fp.tell())
    ...:     print(i)
36
sfdsfsdfefecv

36
dfasd

36
dfasefdf

36
dsfe

36
f
```

If the `file` is big enough, the `fp.tell()` will keep same for a while, it indicates that python read a certain size block once.

Can anyone make `for i in open(file)` work like `python3`(a generator), or give an explanations/authoritative source about how `for i in open(file)` work in `python2`  ,thanks!

Comment: `for index, line in enumerate(fp):`

Comment: @zondo `index` is just `linenumber`, but I want `currently position`, thanks any way!

Comment: `index = 0; for i in fp: index += len(i) ...`

Comment: @zondo add `counter` seems to be the only way currently , however, I'm still looking for much more compatible way in using `for i in open(file)`.Thanks for all !